# linux - ps have different column with process ID

Tags: linux, ps, kill-process

I have simple Docker's command to kill database process:

```
docker exec  app-pgsql bash -c 'ps axuf |grep ils |cut -d" " -f3 |xargs kill -9 || :'
```

and as you can see, I'm looking for 3rd column from `ps` to get process ID but sometimes this column is different, one time 3rd, second time 4th, next time again 3rd, etc.
Is there any better solution to resolve this, no matter what's column will be?

Comment: Rather than using `ps -->  filter on process-name --> extract PID --> kill PID` use the dedicated utility [`pkill`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pkill)  that allows you simply send the desired kill signal directly to a process by **name**

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: as @HBruijn said in the comment, use pkill, because using the method in your question is fragile, to say the least.

If you still want to stick with `ps | filter_it | kill_it`, I'll try to pinpoint some errors in the command you're trying to run. This may not answer your question, but it would be a bit too long to include it as a comment, so here we are.

First, I don't understand how the process ID could end up in different columns, for me, when I use `ps axuf`, the PID is in the second column. Maybe it is another version of `ps` you're using which have different defaults. You can control the output of `ps` with the `-o` switch, so if you use something like

```
ps -ho pid,command
```

then the PID will always be in the first column.

Second, if you use grep, you probably want to use a second `grep -v` as well. When piping commands, the shell will keep all processes alive. Since `grep ils` itself contains `ils`, it could very well end up in your final list. So if you use `grep` to filter, be sure to exclude `grep` itself, like this:

```
ps -ho pid,command | grep ils | grep -v grep
```

Third, using `cut` is a bad way of processing columnar texts, for if there are two delimiters, `cut` will treat the input as having an extra empty column, rendering the output ambiguous (kind of). Use something else, like `awk`.

So your final command should look like this:

```
ps -ho pid,command | grep ils | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}' | xargs kill -9
```

In this case, instead of using `awk`, you could use `cut` (or really anything, e.g. `sed`), since the PID is guaranteed to be the first column, so `cut` would do. I rarely use `cut` and try to avoid it, hence, `awk`. :)

A final note: using `kill -9` is usually considered as a "last resort". You should try to have a normal way of ending the process, since `kill -9` will end the process no matter what, which can cause all kinds of funny effects, especially with databases.